# MeteorJS: Hard time understanding Subscribing/Publishing

Tags: meteor

I have an app that loads a `Jobs` collection on startup.

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('jobs', Session.get('currentIndustryOnet'));
});
```

I am setting the jobs like so for Handlebars:

```
Template.list.jobs = function() {
  var jobs;

  Deps.autorun(function(){
    if(Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')) {
      console.log(Jobs.find({onet: Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')}).count());
    }
  });

  if(Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')) {
    jobs = Jobs.find({onet: Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')});
  } else {
    jobs = Jobs.find({})
  }

  Session.set('jobCount', jobs.count());
  return Pagination.collection(jobs.fetch());
}
```

Also, the `Session.get('currentIndustryOnet')` is set by a click event from a dropdown list

I am confused on why you should have to set the `jobs` in the template if it auto-updates in the Deps.autorun?

Answer (score 1):

`Meteor.subscribe('jobs', ...)` asks the server to publish a set of jobs documents to the client-side database (minimongo) for use in your templates. [This blog post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/) gives a good explanation of how this works. It should be noted that the string `'jobs'` does not need to have anything to do with the collection - it's simply an identifier which should match a publish function on the server side. For example, it could have been called, 'jobsForCurrentIndustryOnet' (that's probably a better name).

After subscribing for the needed subset of the database, the client will reactively redraw the jobs in your templates based on session variables and the result of `Jobs.find` calls.

Note that your template helpers should be primarily concerned with retrieving and manipulating data. They should not include calls to subscriptions and autoruns. In your case, you should remove the `Deps.autorun` inside of the `jobs` helper because a new `autorun` gets created every time the `jobs` helper gets evaluated (could be often depending on how your reactive variables are changing).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Then inside of my jobs helper, would I need to reference the Session'ed variable to look up jobs that only pertain to the selection in the drop down menu?

Comment: Inside of your helpers, you should use your session data so the result will be recomputed. For example, the `Jobs.find` section of your example looks right. If you need to limit the selection by other criteria, those should also be read from session variables and added to the query.